# kendo combobox & kendo-knockout dynamic add/remove next available value set

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

The issue happens when I try to set the next available value in combobox, here is what my scenario is.

I have a list of available items which I display in a combobox, user can select one item & assign at which point I add it to a list/table, user can remove an item from selected at which point it goes back into available list.

Now the issue occurs when the following is done
 1) Select & assign couple of items (notice next available item is selected in combobox)
 2) Remove an item from the selected list/table (item should now be available to select in combobox)
 3) Now try to select the same item & Assign again & notice the next available value in combobox.

Here is a jsFiddle where issue can be reproduced (works only on chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/navnitmehta/fHXBx/7/

I am not sure if this is an issue with kendo or kendo-knockout binding.

Thanks!

Comment: This one is getting addressed here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-kendo/issues/12#issuecomment-6139590

Comment: Did you ever resolved it? It seems if not very same, then very similar problem to what I am experiencing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833710/kendo-combobox-inside-tbody-tr-td-wont-open